# Looking for appropriate design pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Our code has several processors, each one having several api methods, where each method is overloaded also with same method that can accept collection.
For example:

```
public class Foo {
    public X foo(Y y){...}
    public Collection<X> foo(Collection<Y> y){... // iterate and execute foo(y) ... }
    public Z bar(W w){...}
    public Collection<Z> bar(Collection<W> w){... // iterate and execute bar(w) ... }
}
public class Other{
    // also method and method on collection
}
```

Naturally, those methods on collections are actually duplication code of iteration.
What we are looking for, is kind of way to make some pattern or use generics, so the **iteration over collection will be implemented once**, also for that need a way to somehow pass the method name.

Comment: Have you tried methods with variable number of parameters?

Comment: This is not Java's strong suit; closures are planned for a future version of the language, but in the meantime the only ways to abstract over a method are (1) to create an interface, and instead of having methods named `foo` and `bar`, you'd have a single method named `foobar` that's implemented by different implementations of that interface, or (2) to use reflection.

Comment: @Zakub - what do you mean exactly? `foo(Y.. y)` ? This will not solve it since we need to have one method return `X` and other `Collection<X>`.

Comment: @ruakh - 1. main issue to remain with same API, meaning keep the exact methods, but just to save the iteration code, so `foobar()` would not fit, as mentioned one should return `X` and other `Collection<X>`. 2. Any nice solution with reflection you can advise? Anyway to actually get some how the name of `foo(Collection<Y> y)` so I would not need to hard cod the string `"foo"`? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Startegy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). And do something like:

```
public interface Transformer<X, Y> {
    Y transform( X input );
}

class Processor {

    public <X,Y> Collection<Y> process( Collection<X> input, Transformer<X, Y> transformer) {
        Collection<Y> ret = new LinkedList<Y>();
        // generic loop, delegating transformation to specific transformer
        for( X x : input) {
            ret.add( transformer.transform( x ) );
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
        List<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
        strings.add( "1" );
        strings.add( "2" );
        strings.add( "3" );

        Processor p = new Processor();

        Collection<Integer> numbers = p.process( strings, new Transformer<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer transform( String input ) {
                return Integer.parseInt( input );
            }
        } );
    }
```

Comment: - stemm - but it does not solve the issue of having several method names in same class. Maint point - application exists, we do not create it from scratch, just trying to improve. Currently going for the reflection suggested above.

Comment: @urir, the all is needed is only method `process`: instead of creating different methods - just pass specific implementation of transformer strategy into method `process` (in point of call, of course, you have to specify which strategy you want to use)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how reflection could help here. You're trying to replace something as trivial as

```
public Collection<X> foo(Collection<Y> y) {
    List<X> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Y e : y) result.add(foo(e));
    return result;
}
```

by something probably much slower. I don't think that saving those 3 lines (several times) is worth it, but you might want to try either annotation processing (possibly without using annotations) or dynamic code generation. In both cases you'd write the original class as is without the collection methods and use a different one containing both the scalar and the collection methods.

---

Or you might want to make it more functionally styled:

```
public class Foo {
    public final RichFunction<Y, X> foo = new RichFunction<Y, X>() {
        X apply(Y y) {
            return foo(y);
        }
    }

    // after some refactoring the original method can be made private
    // or inlined into the RichFunction
    public X foo(Y y){...}

    // instead of calling the original method like
    // foo.foo(y)
    // you'd use
    // foo.foo.apply(y)
    // which would work for both the scalar and collection methods
}

public abstract class RichFunction<K, V> extends com.google.common.base.Function<K, V> {
    Collection<V> apply(Collection<K> keys) {
        List<V> result = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (K k : keys) result.add(apply(k));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RUAKH - I chosed to implement your suggestion for reflection (although, admit, I don't like reflection). So, I did something like the code below THANKS :)

```
public class Resource {
    private static final int CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX;
    static {
        // Finds out the index of "this code" in the returned stack trace - funny but it differs in JDK 1.5 and 1.6
        int i = 0;
        for (StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            i++;
            if (ste.getClassName().equals(Resource.class.getName())) {
                break;
            }
        }
        CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX = i;
    }
    public static String getCurrentMethodName() {
        return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[CLIENT_CODE_STACK_INDEX].getMethodName();
    }
    protected <IN,OUT> Collection<OUT> doMultiple(String methodName, Collection<IN> inCol, Class<?>... parameterTypes){
        Collection<OUT> result = new ArrayList<OUT>();
        try {
            Method m = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
            if (inCol==null || inCol.size()==0){
                return result;
            }
            for (IN in : inCol){
                Object o = m.invoke(this, in);
                result.add((OUT) o);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class FirstResource extends Resource{
    public String doSomeThing(Integer i){
        // LOTS OF LOGIC
        return i.toString();
    }
    public Collection<String> doSomeThing(Collection<Integer> ints){
        return doMultiple(getCurrentMethodName(), ints, Integer.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Strategy pattern. By using Strategy pattern you can omit the usage if/else which makes the code more complex. Where strategy pattern creates less coupled code which is much simpler. By using Strategy pattern you can achieve more ways to configure code dynamically. So I would like to suggest you to use Strategy pattern.